# How can I figure out what's wrong with this code?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can't get this code to work properly even though its the exact same as what's written in the sample.

```
UPDATE
    (
            SELECT p.product_id,
                    p.product_name,
                    p.clothing,
                    p.color,
                    p.department,
                    p.product_details
            FROM    products p ) p
 SET    p.clothing = Substr(product_name, Instr(product_name, ' ',1,1)+1, Instr(product_name, ' ',1, 2)+1 - Instr(product_name, ' ',1,1)- 2),
    p.color =
    (
            SELECT  c.color
            FROM    json_table (p.product_details, '$' COLUMNS ( color VARCHAR2(4000) path '$.color') ) c),
    p.department =
    (
            SELECT  g.department =
            FROM    json_table (p.product_details, '$' COLUMNS (department VARCHAR2(4000) path '$.gender') ) g);*
```

Trying to run the code returns this:

```
Error at line 17/34: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 797 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 782 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2035
```

I've tried looking into what all the different ORAs mean and addressing them, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `SELECT g.department = FROM` This is not valid SQL. There could be other issues, but that's the first I saw.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has various syntax error and can be simplified to:

```sql
UPDATE products
SET    clothing   = Substr(
                      product_name,
                      Instr(product_name, ' ', 1, 1) + 1,
                      Instr(product_name, ' ', 1, 2)
                        - Instr(product_name, ' ', 1, 1) - 1
                    ),
       color      = JSON_VALUE(product_details, '$.color'),
       department = JSON_VALUE(product_details, '$.gender')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE products(
  product_name    VARCHAR2(50),
  product_details CLOB CHECK (product_details IS JSON),
  clothing        VARCHAR2(20),
  color           VARCHAR2(20),
  department      VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO products (product_name, product_details)
VALUES ('ABC Shirt DEF', '{"color":"Red", "gender": "Female"}');
```

Then, after the `UPDATE` the table contains:

| PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_DETAILS | CLOTHING | COLOR | DEPARTMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC Shirt DEF | {"color":"Red", "gender": "Female"} | Shirt | Red | Female |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pREr9VHd)